# Why is only one of the three descriptions possible? (Understanding Analysis Exercise 3.2.10)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm working through Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* and am stuck on Exercise 3.2.10. Here's the question:

> Only one of the following three descriptions can be realized. Provide an example that illustrates the viable description, and explain why the other two cannot exist.
>
> i) A countable set contained in $[0,1]$ with no limit points.
> ii) A countable set contained in $[0,1]$ with no isolated points.
> iii) A set with an uncountable number of isolated points.

I came up with a proof that (iii) cannot exist, but I don't see why both (i) and (ii) can't work. The set $\{ \frac{1}{2} \}$ would work for (i) since it's countable and doesn't have any limit points. (His definition for limit point is as follows: A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point other than $x$.)

And $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ would work for (ii). Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, its intersection with $[0,1]$ is as well. This set has no isolated points because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$: for every $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ such that $|r-q| < \epsilon$.

But, apparently, either (i) or (ii) cannot exist. Why is my reasoning here incorrect?

Comment: I suppose the issue here is that "countable" means "countably infinite".

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, I see. In that case, then (i) wouldn't work because of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, right? Since $A$ is countable, its elements can be listed as $a_1, ...$, and in that list there exists a convergent subsequence. That would be a limit point.

Comment: If I understand the intention of the problem correctly, yes, that's precisely it.

Comment: Exactly one exists is what he claims and that's correct. You identified the correct one. The first cannot be finite, and many authors exclude finite from countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! As pointed out by @Wojowu, the set has to be countably infinite. So (i) wouldn't work because of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Since $A$ is countable, its elements can be listed as $a_1,...$, and in that list there exists a convergent subsequence. The limit of this sequence would be a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

The first cannot exist as $[0,1]$ is limit point compact. The second obviously exists as $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ shows. And for every space with a countable base we also have a countable base for any subset, so no uncountable discrete subset can exist.